# Example of Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $A=[a,b] \times \{c\}$, where $b>a.$ Then $\forall \epsilon >0$ $$ A\subset I_k = [a,b]\times\biggr[c-\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)},c+\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}\biggr].$$

Now $\mu(I_k)=\epsilon.$ A has measure zero if $\forall\epsilon>0$, there exists compact intervals $I_k$ such that $A\subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$  and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(I_k)=\mu(I_k)<\epsilon.$ Can I now use the arbitrariness of the first $\epsilon'$ to claim that $\mu(I_k)=\epsilon'<\epsilon\enspace ?$, and thus giving $A$ zero measure. Supposedly this is correct, but both of these $\epsilon$ are arbitrary and this confuses me.

Comment: Start with any $\epsilon ' >0$ and choose $\epsilon \in (0,\epsilon')$. Then you have found a compact set containing $A$ whose measure is less than $\epsilon'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to prove that $A$ has measure $0$, which is the same as proving that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\mu(A)\leq\varepsilon$. Take any $\varepsilon$ and take $$I_\varepsilon=[a,b]\times\left[c-\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)},c+\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)}\right]$$
Clearly $A\subset I_\varepsilon,\forall\varepsilon>0$ so $\mu(A)\leq\mu(I_\varepsilon)=\varepsilon$, and we just proved that $\mu(A)=0$.

So you don't need to pick two arbitrary $\varepsilon$ just one.